# How do I set a session expiration date in redis node.js without maxAge?

Tags: node.js, session, redis

I have this code:

```
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
   host: 'localhost',
   port: 6379,
   ttl: 10
});

app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient });,
  secret: 'some secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: true,
    maxAge: 60*1000
  }
}));
```

And everything works as it should. After the `maxAge` expires, redis is also cleared. But if you delete `maxAge` and leave `ttl`, then redis will never be cleared, how to clear redis without specifying `maxAge`, because the user can change the value of the cookie `maxAge` to `null`, and then redis will never be cleared. Can I somehow specify the expiration time directly in redis and not in cookies? Or did I get something wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [`connect-redis` docs under the `ttl` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis#ttl) - "If the session cookie has a expires date, connect-redis will use it as the TTL.".

So in you're case - both the cookie and the key in redis will be cleared on expiration.

And even if the client will somehow change the cookie expiration time, it won't effect redis (so the cookie might be sent over the HTTP request, but the server won't recognize it).

(You didn't mentioned which modules you're using, I'm just assuming its `express-session` and `connect-redis`)

Comment: Yes, that's right, I use `express-session` and `connect-redis`. Your answer helped me, thank you very much.